Why does Xdebug show different versions of PHP for `Run Time` and `Compile Time`?
I installed php-xdebug on my Debian 12 VM. When I run xdebug_info(), the PHP Build Configuration reports different versions of PHP for Run Time and Compile Time.

Version (Run Time) = 8.3.12
Version (Compile Time) = 8.3.6

Xdebug Output:

The Debian server is new, and has only had one version (8.3) of PHP installed using the deb.sury.org package.
I'm using the built-in PHP webserver. php -S 0.0.0.0:8888
php -v
PHP 8.3.12 (cli) (built: Sep 27 2024 04:03:53) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.3.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.3.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

The PHP version reported by php_info() is 8.3.12. There are no references to 8.3.6.
PHP Info Output:


The Xdebug version is 3.3.2, which is the latest stable version.
php -i | grep Xdebug
    with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

I used this script that I wrote to install PHP, among other packages and tools. There isn't too much of anything else installed on the server.
PHP Install Script:
## Setup PHP Repo
echo "\e[47m\e[31mInstall PHP source repository...\e[0m"
curl -sSLo /tmp/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb https://packages.sury.org/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb
dpkg -i /tmp/debsuryorg-archive-keyring.deb
sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deb.sury.org-php.gpg] https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
apt-get update

## Install PHP and Extensions
# FPM and CLI are installed first to remove Apache dependency
# Thanks https://askubuntu.com/users/583418/dan-delaney
# https://askubuntu.com/a/1357414
echo "\e[47m\e[31mInstalling PHP 8.3 FPM and CLI...\e[0m"
apt-get -y install php8.3-fpm php8.3-cli
echo "\e[47m\e[31mInstalling PHP 8.3...\e[0m"
apt-get -y install php8.3
echo "\e[47m\e[31mInstalling PHP 8.3 Extensions...\e[0m"
apt-get -y install php8.3-common php8.3-curl php8.3-mbstring php8.3-sqlite3 php8.3-xml php8.3-zip

Xdebug was manually installed later from package repository: apt install php-xdebug.
sudo apt install php-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php8.3-xdebug
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-xdebug php8.3-xdebug
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 628 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,022 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm/main amd64 php8.3-xdebug amd64 3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8 [622 kB]
Get:2 https://packages.sury.org/php bookworm/main amd64 php-xdebug amd64 3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8 [5,512 B]
Fetched 628 kB in 1s (852 kB/s)        
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend requires a screen at least 13 lines tall and 31 columns wide.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously unselected package php8.3-xdebug.
(Reading database ... 32960 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php8.3-xdebug_3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php8.3-xdebug (3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-xdebug.
Preparing to unpack .../php-xdebug_3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php-xdebug (3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8) ...
Setting up php8.3-xdebug (3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8) ...
Setting up php-xdebug (3.3.2-1+0~20240420.60+debian12~1.gbp3869a8) ...
Processing triggers for php8.3-cli (8.3.12-1+0~20240927.43+debian12~1.gbpad3b8c) ...
Processing triggers for php8.3-fpm (8.3.12-1+0~20240927.43+debian12~1.gbpad3b8c) ...


Version (Compile Time) is the PHP version used to compile the xdebug extension and is not very useful, regardless of the PHP version you currently have installed.

Thanks for the information. I removed the apt package and built xdebug from source, and now the versions match. Much appreciated.
